# How to use inner query to fetch data from salesforce to mule?

Tags: salesforce, mule

I wrote below query to fetch data from salesforce but getting error like "Unknown error parsing query"

```
select Email,Id from contact where Email in (select b.Email from contact as b group by b.Email having count(b.id) < 2 limit 1000)
```

inner query alone retrieving the set of mail Ids, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the issue is not related with the query / organisation ?

Using SOQL workbench --> https://workbench.developerforce.com

and getting this error:

MALFORMED_QUERY: 
(select b.Email from contact as b group by b.Email having count(b.id)
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:78
expecting a right parentheses, found 'group'

Comment: Hi, Inner query is working fine which gives mail address and number of times it is repeated but when i combine with outer query it is throwing that error message.

Comment: seems like something related to SOQL , i would say

Answer (score 0):

You can first check your query on Salesforce using developer console if its working or not.

If its returning required result in Salesforce then it will work in Mulesoft as well.